# Specific WordPress permalinks link to wrong page

Tags: wordpress

I have a somewhat strange issue with WordPress today. This behaviour has only begun in the last week or so as far as I can ascertain.

Any page with the slug "downloads" links to it's parent page instead of to it's own page.

I have tried the following:

1. Reset permalinks to default and then back to %postname%
2. Disabled all plugins
3. Physically cleared the cache

But none of the above fix the issue. The weird thing is that this behaviour is only happening for pages with the slug "downloads". For all other slugs it is fine.

For example there are multiple instances of the slug "get-involved" with different parents and all work fine. But when the same is done with "downloads" the links redirect to their parent. Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

I have also verified in fiddler that the pages are not redirecting, they are actually linking to the parent page with a response code of 200, there is no 301 or 302 thrown.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will automatically duplicate the same slug with a new name but you should check again, maybe you've re-writing slug manually before. And check your .htaccess.

Comment: Don't forget to check your trash too.

Comment: Yeah thats one of the first things that I did but there are no redirects/rewrites anywhere and none in the trash. this seems to only have kicked in after an auto update. My suspicion is something had gotten upset in the DB. I'm going to run some queries in the next few days when time allows to see whats up, since it only happens with any page with a slug of "downloads". Thanks for the suggestions anyway.